# How do I add foreign Key to mariadb?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to create a table in mariadb, but each time I try adding a foreign key it returns an error message. When I try to create the table without the foreign key it works.
Here is the code without the foreign key that executes.

```
create table countries(
   country_id int(249) auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   area decimal(10,2) not null,
   national_day date,
   region_id int not null);
```

Here is the sql where I add the foreign key

```
create table countries(
   country_id int(249) auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   area decimal(10,2) not null,
   national_day date,
   region_id int not null,
   foreign key(region_id)
);
```

the error I get when I try it is the following
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1`
i have also tried

```
create table countries(
   country_id int(249) auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   area decimal(10,2) not null,
   national_day date,
   region_id int not null foreign key
);
```

it still gives me the error, I feel that it should be easy to add a foreign key but I am lost.

Comment: Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/h8oFhxao   More info, see: [(docs:) Using Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/8.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: And the MariaDB [Foreign key manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/) which needs a `REFERENCES` table in the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the manual tells you the correct [form][1] of the foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE region(id int Primary KEY auto_increment);
```

```
create table countries(
   country_id INT unsigned auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   area decimal(10,2) not null,
   national_day date,
   region_id int not null,
   foreign key(region_id) references region(id)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mad2XCl_)

Comment: Its working as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Please remove (249) it has no effect without ZEROFILL and change INT to INT UNSIGNED.

Answer (score 1):

try this code
You have not given a reference to the table

```
create table countries(
   country_id int(249) auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   area decimal(10,2) not null,
   national_day date,
   region_id int not null);

create table region(
   country_id int(249) auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   area decimal(10,2) not null,
   national_day date,
   region_id int not null,
   add constraint foreign key(region_id) references countries(region_id);
```

Comment: Could you _try_ to format your answer correctly ? In general an answer should not be something needing to **try**. You tested it, and it is correct! No need in trying anymore....

Comment: okay i will keep this in mind next time